# Error : set returning functions are not allowed in CASE, in Postgresql 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgres-10

sql is not my strong point

upgrading from postgres 9.6 to 10.6 and I get an error from this query:

```
select 
    CASE WHEN wlh.status_reason_code like '%DR%' THEN
            concat('RR',jsonb_array_elements_text(replace(wlh.status_reason_code,'DR','')::jsonb))      
    ELSE
        ''
    END 
from workflow.workflow_log_history wlh
```

**error: set returning functions are not allowed in CASE**

result i get back (from v 9.6):

| Concat |
| --- |
| RR9 |
| RR8 |

any help please been stuck on this for a while

Comment: What part of *you can't return a set in a CASE* isn't clear?

Comment: Does the array have more than one element?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the input looks like (the content of `status_reason_code`). Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample input data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: `jsonb_array_elements_text()` returns SQL table (SETOF `text`) - which is not a suitable argument for `concat()`. You should probably move it to the FROM clause.

Comment: Your example output isn't much use without also knowing the example input which lead to it.

Comment: This change is described in the release notes https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/10.0/